# Twig: adding twig extension debug from config file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

According to TWIG documentation, in order to use the dump function I should first add the extension debug like so:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
'debug' => true,
// ...
 ));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

But how do I do that from config.yml  ? I use symfony2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging) should be defined as follow,

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    custom.twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extension_Debug
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Comment: For Symfony 3 it is exactly the same