# How to enable \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.8

The [Twig documentation for `dump()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/functions/dump.html) says:

> The `dump` function is not available by default. You must add the `\Twig\Extension\DebugExtension` extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment:
>
> ```php
> $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
>     'debug' => true,
>     // ...
> ]);
> $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension());
> ```
>
> Even when enabled, the `dump` function won't display anything if the `debug` option on the environment is not enabled (to avoid leaking debug information on a production server).

I have no code anywhere that looks remotely like `new \Twig\Environment`. It's done automatically by Symfony, so how can I set `\Twig\Extension\DebugExtension` on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig: adding twig extension debug from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362495/twig-adding-twig-extension-debug-from-config-file)

Comment: @Rain, yes that was 80% of the problem.